# How to follow a person on Delve (Office 365)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

When I go the delve page of any of the user I am not able to follow that person, since the 'Follow' link is not available on that user's delve page.

Can any one help me out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of  "Following Content feature" was not activated in the site level. Go to Site Settings, click on Manage Site Features under Site Actions section. Activate the Following content feature now you can be able to see the Follow option in the team site.

Answer (score 1):

Office Delve isn’t implemented to ”follow” a person or site, which you do your Office 365 SharePoint Sites. Instead, Office Delve let you see your colleagues who have started using Delve. Clicking a person’s name let you see the relevant Delve content this user have interacted with, which is the closest thing to “following” you get. You can also search for users in the search area and the relevant content appears where this user is mentioned. You can also add content to collections and name theme thereafter, as a specific customer or a project.

[image]

> ## [What is Office Delve?](https://support.office.com/en-my/article/What-is-Office-Delve-1315665a-c6af-4409-a28d-49f8916878ca)
>
> Delve helps you discover the information that's likely to be most interesting to you right now - across Office 365. You don't have to remember the title of a document or where it's stored. Delve shows you documents no matter where they're stored in OneDrive for Business or in Sites in Office 365.
>
> Delve also lets you view your colleagues' profiles, or edit your own. Your profile is like an electronic business card you share inside your organization.
>
> Delve never changes any permissions, so you'll only see documents that you already have access to. Other people will not see your private documents. Learn more about privacy.
>
> When you and your colleagues view, edit, and share each other's documents, Delve learns from how you work and tailors the information to each of you on your personalized Home page. What you see in Delve is different from what your colleagues see.
>
> Here are a couple of suggestions to get you started with using Delve:
>
> Click someone’s name or picture to see the documents they’re working on, or to view their profile.
>
> Search for a topic you’re interested in and see what you find.
>
> **Powertip:** When you find a document you’re interested in, try adding it to a board to easily get back to it later.